# При включенном фильтре на странице категорий, ломается вывод опций

Tags: php, opencart, filter

Добрый день друзья подскажите кто знает, у меня такая проблема, на странице категорий вывожу опции, вывожу их таким образом. В контроллер добавляю следующие:

```
    1. После: 

        $this->load->language('product/category');

    Добавить: 

        $this->load->language('product/product');

    2. После: 

        $data['button_grid'] = $this->language->get('button_grid');

    Добавить:

        $data['text_select'] = $this->language->get('text_select');

    3. Перед

        $data['products'][] = array(
        'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
    /* НАЧАЛО Вывод опций на странице категорий */



     $json = array();

        if (isset($this->request->post['product_id'])) {
        $product_id = $this->request->post['product_id'];
        } else {
        $product_id = 0;
        }


        $this->load->model('catalog/product');


        $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);


        if ($product_info) {


        $options = array();


        foreach($this>model_catalog_product>getProductOptions($product_info['product_id']) as $option) {$product_option_value_data = array();
        foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {
         if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
         if ((($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) && (float)$option_value['price']) {
            $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($option_value['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax') ? 'P' : false));
        } else {
        $price = false;
        }
        $product_option_value_data[] = array(
        'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
        'option_value_id' => $option_value['option_value_id'],
        'name' => $option_value['name'],
        'image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
        'price' => $price,
        'price_prefix' => $option_value['price_prefix']
        );
        }
        }введите сюда код
        $options[] = array(
        'product_option_id' => $option['product_option_id'],
        'option_value' => $product_option_value_data,
        'option_id' => $option['option_id'],
        'name' => $option['name'],
        'type' => $option['type'],
        'value' => $option['value'],
        'required' => $option['required']
        );


        $options['product_id'] = $product_info['product_id'];
        $options['name'] = $product_info['name'];
        } 


        if (!$json) {
        $json = $options;
        }
        }
        /* Конец Вывод опций на странице категорий */


код фильтра вот:
<?php
/******************************************************
 * @package AveThemes Framework Opencart 2.x
 * @version 1.0
 * @author http://www.avethemes.com
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) January 2015 www.avethemes.com <@emai:avethemes@gmail.com@gmail.com>.All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2
*******************************************************/
class ControllerAvethemesAveProductFilter extends Controller {
    public function index($setting=array()) {
        if(defined('ave_check')){
        $language_data = $this->load->language('avethemes/shortcode_product_filter');
        foreach($language_data as $key=>$value){
            $data[$key] = $value;
        }   
        $data['ave']  = $this->ave;

        $data['currency_code']  = $this->session->data['currency'];
        $data['setting'] = $setting;

            $ave_shortcodes_filter_setting = $this->config->get('ave_shortcodes_filter_setting');


        if(isset($this->request->get['path'])) {

        $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);
        $category_id = array_pop($parts);
        $this->load->model('avethemes/filter_product');

        $data['manufacturers'] = false;
        if(isset($ave_shortcodes_filter_setting['display_manufacturer'])){
            if($ave_shortcodes_filter_setting['display_manufacturer'] != 'none') {
                $data['manufacturers'] = $this->model_avethemes_filter_product->getManufacturersByCategoryId($category_id);
                $data['display_manufacturer'] = $ave_shortcodes_filter_setting['display_manufacturer'];
            }
        }
        $data['options'] = $this->model_avethemes_filter_product->getOptionsByCategoryId($category_id);
        foreach($data['options'] as $i => $option) {            
                    if(isset($ave_shortcodes_filter_setting['display_option_' . $option['option_id']])){
                        $display_option = $ave_shortcodes_filter_setting['display_option_' . $option['option_id']];
                        if($display_option != 'none') {
                            $data['options'][$i]['display'] = $display_option;
                        }else{
                            $data['options'][$i]['display'] = 'none';
                        }
                    } else {
                        unset($data['options'][$i]);
                    }

        }

        $data['attributes'] = $this->model_avethemes_filter_product->getAttributesByCategoryId($category_id);

        foreach($data['attributes'] as $j => $attribute_group) {
            foreach($attribute_group['attribute_values'] as $attribute_id => $attribute) {

                    if(isset($ave_shortcodes_filter_setting['display_attribute_' . $attribute_id])){
                        $display_attribute = $ave_shortcodes_filter_setting['display_attribute_' . $attribute_id];
                        if($display_attribute != 'none') {
                            $data['attributes'][$j]['attribute_values'][$attribute_id]['display'] = $display_attribute;                         
                        }else{
                            unset($data['attributes'][$j]['attribute_values'][$attribute_id]);
                            if(!$data['attributes'][$j]['attribute_values']) {
                                unset($data['attributes'][$j]);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                            unset($data['attributes'][$j]['attribute_values'][$attribute_id]);
                            if(!$data['attributes'][$j]['attribute_values']) {
                                unset($data['attributes'][$j]);
                            }
                    }

            }
        }

        $data['category_id'] = $category_id;
        $data['path'] = $this->request->get['path'];

        $this->document->addStyle('assets/editor/shortcode/filter/filter.css');

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $data['sort'] = $this->request->get['sort'];
        } else {
            $data['sort'] = 'p.sort_order';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $data['order'] = $this->request->get['order'];
        } else {
            $data['order'] = 'ASC';
        }


        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $data['page'] = $this->request->get['page'];
        } else {
            $data['page'] = 1;
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $data['limit'] = $this->request->get['limit'];
        } else {
            if((int)substr((string)str_replace('.','',VERSION),0,3) > 210) {
                $data['limit'] = $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit');
            }else{
                $data['limit'] = $this->config->get('config_product_limit');
            }
        }
        $priceLimits = $this->model_avethemes_filter_product->getPriceLimits(array('category_id' => $category_id));
            $data['pmin'] = $this->currency->convert($priceLimits['pmin'], $this->config->get('config_currency'), $this->session->data['currency']);
            $data['pmax'] = $this->currency->convert($priceLimits['pmax'], $this->config->get('config_currency'), $this->session->data['currency']);

                if((int)substr((string)str_replace('.','',VERSION),0,3) > 210) {
                    $this_template = 'avethemes/required/shortcode_product_filter';
                }elseif(file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE.$this->config->get('config_template').'/template/avethemes/required/shortcode_product_filter.tpl')) {
                    $this_template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/avethemes/required/shortcode_product_filter.tpl';
                } else {
                    $this_template = 'default/template/avethemes/required/shortcode_product_filter.tpl';
                }           
                return $this->load->view($this_template, $data);
            }
        }
    }

    private function array_clean(array $haystack) {
        foreach($haystack as $key => $value) {
            if(is_array($value)) {
                $haystack[$key] = $this->array_clean($value);
                if(!count($haystack[$key])) {
                    unset($haystack[$key]);
                }
            } elseif(is_string($value)) {
                $value = trim($value);
                if(!$value) {
                    unset($haystack[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $haystack;
    }

    public function parse_filter_data() {
        $language_data = $this->load->language('avethemes/shortcode_product_filter');

            $ave_shortcodes_filter_setting = $this->config->get('ave_shortcodes_filter_setting');
            $page = 1;

        if(isset($this->request->post['page'])) {
            $page = (int)$this->request->post['page'];
        }
        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
        }elseif(isset($this->request->post['sort'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->post['sort'];
        }else{
            $sort = 'p.sort_order';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['order'];
        }elseif(isset($this->request->post['order'])) {
            $order = $this->request->post['order'];
        }else{
            $order = 'ASC';
        }
        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $sort = $this->request->get['limit'];
        }elseif(isset($this->request->post['limit'])) {
            $limit = $this->request->post['limit'];
        }else{

            if((int)substr((string)str_replace('.','',VERSION),0,3) > 210) {
                $limit = $this->config->get($this->config->get('config_theme') . '_product_limit');
            }else{
                $limit = $this->config->get('config_product_limit');
            }
        }


        $this->load->model('avethemes/filter_product');
/*      $this->load->model('catalog/product');*/
        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $manufacturer = false;
        if(isset($this->request->post['manufacturer'])) {
            $manufacturer = $this->array_clean($this->request->post['manufacturer']);
            if(!count($manufacturer)) {
                $manufacturer = false;
            }
        }

        $option_value = false;
        if(isset($this->request->post['option_value'])) {
            $option_value = $this->array_clean($this->request->post['option_value']);
            if(!count($option_value)) {
                $option_value = false;
            }
        }

        $attribute_value = false;
        if(isset($this->request->post['attribute_value'])) {
            $attribute_value = $this->array_clean($this->request->post['attribute_value']);
            if(!count($attribute_value)) {
                $attribute_value = false;
            }
        }

        $pid = isset($this->request->post['pid'])?$this->request->post['pid']:false; 
        $pmin = isset($this->request->post['pmin'])?$this->request->post['pmin']:false; 
        $pmax = isset($this->request->post['pmax'])?$this->request->post['pmax']:false;
        $filter_data = array(
            'option_value' => $option_value,
            'manufacturer' => $manufacturer,
            'attribute_value' => $attribute_value,
            'category_id' => $pid,
            'pmin' => $pmin,
            'pmax' => $pmax,
            'start' => ($page - 1) * $limit,
            'limit' => $limit,
            'sort' => $sort,
            'order' => $order
        );

        $product_total = $this->model_avethemes_filter_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data);

        $totals_manufacturers = $this->model_avethemes_filter_product->getTotalManufacturers($filter_data);

        $totals_options = $this->model_avethemes_filter_product->getTotalOptions($filter_data);

        $totals_attributes = $this->model_avethemes_filter_product->getTotalAttributes($filter_data);

        $products = $this->model_avethemes_filter_product->getProducts($filter_data);


        $result = array();


        $fmin =  $fmax =  false;

        if(isset($this->request->post['getPriceLimits']) && $this->request->post['getPriceLimits']) {
            $priceLimits = $this->model_avethemes_filter_product->getPriceLimits(array('category_id' => $this->request->post['pid']));
            $fmin = $priceLimits['pmin'];
            $fmax = $priceLimits['pmax'];
        }


        if((int)substr((string)str_replace('.','',VERSION),0,3) > 210) {
            $prefix = $this->config->get('config_theme');
        }else{
            $prefix = 'config';
        }
            $image_product_width = $this->config->get($prefix.'_image_product_width');
            $image_product_height = $this->config->get($prefix.'_image_product_height');
            $product_description_length = $this->config->get($prefix.'_product_description_length');

        $special_label = $this->ave->get('category_special_label');
        $no_image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('placeholder.png', $image_product_width, $image_product_height);

        foreach($products as $product) {
            if ($product['image']&&file_exists(DIR_IMAGE.$product['image'])) {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product['image'], $image_product_width, $image_product_height);
            } else {
                $image = $no_image;
            }

            if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $price = false;
            }


            if ((float)$product['special']&&$special_label==1) {
                $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['special'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
                $sales_percent = str_replace('.00','',number_format((100-(($product['special']*100)/$product['price'])),0));
            } else {
                $special = false;
                $sales_percent =false;
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                $tax = $this->currency->format(((float)$product['special'] ? $product['special'] : $product['price']), $this->session->data['currency']);
            } else {
                $tax = false;
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                $rating = (int)$product['rating'];
            } else {
                $rating = false;
            }


            if($product['quantity'] <= 0) {
                $rstock = $product['stock_status'];
            } elseif($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
                $rstock = $product['quantity'];
            } else {
                $rstock = $this->language->get('text_instock');
            }
            $result[] = array(
                'product_id' => $product['product_id'],
                'sku' => $ave_shortcodes_filter_setting['sku_display'] ? $product['sku'] : false,
                'model' => $ave_shortcodes_filter_setting['model_display'] ? $product['model'] : false,
                'brand' => $ave_shortcodes_filter_setting['brand_display'] ? $product['manufacturer'] : false,
                'location' => $ave_shortcodes_filter_setting['location_display'] ? $product['location'] : false,
                'upc' => $ave_shortcodes_filter_setting['upc_display'] ? $product['upc'] : false,
                'stock' => $ave_shortcodes_filter_setting['stock_display'] ? $rstock : false,
                'image' => $image,
                'thumb' => $image,
                'special' => $special,
                'sales_percent' => $sales_percent,
                'tax' => $tax,
                'rating' => $rating,
                'reviews'     => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$product['reviews']),
                'name' => $product['name'],
                'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($product['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $product_description_length) . '..',
                'price' => $price,
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->post['path'] . '&product_id=' . $product['product_id'])
            );
        }

        $pagination = new Pagination();
        $pagination->total = $product_total;
        $pagination->page = $page;
        $pagination->limit = $limit;
        $pagination->url = 'page={page}';

        $json['pagination']  = $pagination->render();
        $json['pagination_results']  =  sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($product_total) ? ((int)($page - 1) * $limit) + 1 : 0, (((int)($page - 1) * $limit) > (int)($product_total - $limit)) ? $product_total : (((int)($page - 1) * $limit) + $limit), (int)$product_total, (int)ceil($product_total / $limit));


        $pmin = $this->currency->convert($pmin, $this->config->get('config_currency'), $this->session->data['currency']);
        $pmax = $this->currency->convert($pmax, $this->config->get('config_currency'), $this->session->data['currency']);

        $fmin = $this->currency->convert($fmin, $this->config->get('config_currency'), $this->session->data['currency']);
        $fmax = $this->currency->convert($fmax, $this->config->get('config_currency'), $this->session->data['currency']);

        $json['code']    = $this->session->data['currency'];
        $json['pmin']    = $pmin;
        $json['pmax']    = $pmax;
        $json['fmin']    = $fmin;
        $json['fmax']    = $fmax;

        $json['products']    = $result;
        $json['btn_cart']    =  $this->ave->get('category_btn_cart');
        $json['btn_whistlist']   =  $this->ave->get('category_btn_whistlist');
        $json['btn_compare']     =  $this->ave->get('category_btn_compare');


        foreach($language_data as $key=>$value){
            $json[$key] = $value;
        }

        $json['totals_data'] = array(
                                    'manufacturers' => $totals_manufacturers,
                                    'options' => $totals_options,
                                    'attributes' => $totals_attributes
                                );
        if((int)substr((string)str_replace('.','',VERSION),0,3) > 210) {
            $this_template = 'avethemes/required/shortcode_product_filter_results';
        }elseif(file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE.$this->config->get('config_template').'/template/avethemes/required/shortcode_product_filter_results.tpl')) {
            $this_template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/avethemes/required/shortcode_product_filter_results.tpl';
        } else {
            $this_template = 'default/template/avethemes/required/shortcode_product_filter_results.tpl';
        }           
        $json['products_data']   =  $this->load->view($this_template, $json);

        $json_encode =      json_encode($json); 
        $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
        $this->response->setOutput($json_encode);   
    }
}

?>
```

Если фильтр выключен, то опции отображаются и работают на странице категорий, если же я его включаю (фильтр) то ошибка: Undefined variable: options

Comment: покажите полный текст ошибки, так будет видно файл и строку в которой она генерируется. мож чё проясним.

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись, уже решил проблему)